# Appending src to iframe through jquery fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am appending an `iframe` to my html through jquery.
Code is like this.

```
function setImageUrl(imgname) {

   $(".large-image iframe").remove();
    var u = '<iframe width="560" id="iframevideo" height="315" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(".large-image").append(u);   
    document.getElementById('iframevideo').setAttribute("src", imgname); 
return true;
```

}
Parameter **imgname** is coming correctly and it is the intended `Iframe` `src`
But this always produces a blank `iframe`. like this one

[image]

On the  other hand, If i hardcoded the `src` everything works fine.So I assume the issue is some where I am setting `src`.I have tried different methodes ,but nothing works.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, use jQuery. There's no reason you should be using `getElementById` and `setAttribute`. The inconsistency makes your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 document.getElementById('iframevideo').src=imgname;
```

or

```
$('#iframevideo').attr('src', imgname);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is working demo ..

```
function setimage () {
  $("#oldframe").remove();
  $("#main").append("iframe tag ");
  $('#newframe').attr('src', 'imgurl');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ecvj/14/)